# How did the figurative meaning of 'iniungere' develop from the literal one?

Tags: etymology, meaning, prefix

The verb *iniungere* (a compound of *in-* and *iungere*) literally means "to join, fasten, attach".
However, an [Etymonline entry](https://www.etymonline.com/word/enjoin) also gives it a figurative meaning "to inflict, to attack, impose".
How was the meaning generalized from the neutral literal meaning to the somewhat hostile figurative one?

Comment: I rewrote and reopened the question. I think it is much more attractive when written compactly, but it is of course a matter of taste. The Etymonline reference should be sufficient as a link (it is where you found the figurative meaning but all the relevant details are already included here). In general, I would advice to have more of your own text than quotes in a question. Most people seem to prefer to text organized into paragraphs as a question format.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta +1. Thank you . It is surely much more attractive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [r/classics post](https://redd.it/hewp2a) answers my question.

[IonCharge](https://old.reddit.com/user/IonCharge). 19 days ago

> I would hazard a guess and say it was a result of the farming connotation with iugum "yoke" (hence iniungere = to join two bulls together to draw a plough) which had already extended its semantic field to include marriage and slavery. Ultimately the iugum represented some element of mastery and domination, whether over farming animals, women, slaves, etc.

> To join together > to yoke > to enslave > to impose

---

> If this is the case, the semantic shift began around 7-8c BCE. Within a few hundred years of Rome’s founding the Romans would “subjugate” those defeated in battle, if not outright slaughtering them. It’s been a while so my dates may be off, but it was before or during the Hellenistic period when this shift happened.

---

> This could easily be proto-Italic, though I'm sure some Latin speakers were savvy enough to know that iugum and iungere were cognates. I'm going to need a source on that dating.

[breadyly](https://old.reddit.com/user/breadyly). 19 days ago

> idk if this will answer your question, but when joining two things together, it can be either passive or forced, hence the more hostile meaning

[Peteat6](https://old.reddit.com/user/Peteat6). 19 days ago

> I don’t know, but if there’s a fight about it, I want to join in. Haha! See what I did there? Of course you did.